# Postgresql on multiple servers

Tags: database, postgresql, database-performance

Supposing a lot of user access concurrently to a postgresql database. Supposing the database is on a dedicated server which only contains postgresql. Will the database hold ? For 100 users ? 1000 ?

Another question: If i'd like to make it hold no matter how many users, is there a built-in way of separating the database onto several servers or would i have to program the separation myself by installing several postgresql servers and splitting the data ?

Edit: I mean transactions, not the size. And the queries I want to run are simple inserts and selects with joins.

Comment: I doubt you're going to find a hard and fast rule regarding how many users you can support here as how your database performs is going to be dependent on hardware, configuration, number of simultaneous requests, length of the transactions, complexity of your queries, your indexes, and the amount of data in your DB.  However, regarding scaling out PostgreSQL onto multiple servers you should look into PG9 and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/high-availability.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never tried Postgres but MySQL will serve roughly (order of magnitude) 1000 concurrent users on an average PC. After 1000 users it will "not hold". :)

please refer to [this](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling)

Comment: a tip: since websites can get removed, quote the part that you wanted to refer to in particular, or describe what the webpage is about.

Answer (score 1):

I have had 600 concurrent connections to Postgres without performance penalty on a dedicated server, it's the most i've had. But if your planning to have that much you should consider pooled connections as suggested by @bpgergo.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you mean "How many user records can a single database server hold?" or "How many concurrent users (transactions) can a single database server support at a given time?".

In either case, it's going to depend on your server configuration.

Additionally, if you are talking about number of records, it will depend on the size of each record.

If you are talking about transactions, it depends on the kinds of queries you are running.

So, please provide a bit more information.